# NSUserDefaults give Declaration shadows a local variable warning

Tags: ios, c, iphone, xcode

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *bannerViewAdUnitID = [defaults valueForKey:@"admobBannerViewID
```

give "Declaration shadows a local variable warning"

"Previous declaration is here:"

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL admobStatus = [defaults integerForKey:@"admobTurnedOn"];
```

should I remove first instance? or how I can fix this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the second

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

instance. The first `defaults` instance should still be available, so you don't need the second call to `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`.